# How to use JEDI TJCLHashMap classes?

Tags: delphi, hashmap, jedi, jedi-code-library

I'm trying to use TJCLHashMap family of classes, but apparently this class has no useful public methods. All methods are "protected". How to use this class? Although JCL comes with some samples, I seem to miss something. A basic example would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the interfaces declared in JclContainerIntf.pas. The classes in JclHashMaps implement those interfaces.
Take a look at jcl\examples\common\containers\hashing\HashingExample.dpr for a few examples (integer, strings, objects, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Extend it and add public methods that call the protected methods internally?

Comment: shouldn't a generic hash map class has public methods? This would be a tedious job. See Java. :)